# Javascript: How to loop through data object and create a comma separated file

Tags: javascript

I want to create a comma separated file with a few input strings I have and wonder if there is an easier way to do this. My inputs are a combination of variables and data objects.

```
  var textarray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){ //data is my object
    var sms = ('#TxtMessage').val();
    var date = ('#datetxt').val()
    var code = ('#code').val()
    var type = data[i].producttype;
    var mixer = data[i].mixer;
    var quality = data[i].quality;
    textarray.push();
  }
```

But its going in as a continous list of strings. I want each loop to go as a separate line and then convert to csv. I am trying to put it in an array and then convert to text but if we can do it directly I would take that

Comment: How are you converting `textarray` to a CSV right now?

Comment: i am using textarray.join(",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append all of the items, comma separated, to a string in each loop iteration and push it to your `textarray` variable.

After the loop, join the `textarray` with newline escape sequence (\n)

```js
var textarray = [];

var getRandValue = () => {
  var fakeValues = ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolar', 'Sit', 'Amet', 'Bla', 'bla']
  return fakeValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * fakeValues.length)]
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //data is my object
  var sms = getRandValue()
  var date = getRandValue()
  var code = getRandValue()
  var type = getRandValue()
  var mixer = getRandValue()
  var quality = getRandValue()
  var csvLine = `${sms}, ${date}, ${code}, ${type}, ${mixer}, ${quality}`
  textarray.push(csvLine)
}

var resultCSV = textarray.join('\n')

var output = document.getElementById('output')

output.innerText = resultCSV
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternately use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) of the array prototype.

After processing, you get the csv string

```js
const data = [{
  producttype: 'type1',
  mixer: 'mixer1',
  quality: 'quality1'
},{
  producttype: 'type2',
  mixer: 'mixer2',
  quality: 'quality2'
},{
  producttype: 'type3',
  mixer: 'mixer3',
  quality: 'quality3'
}];

const sms = $('#TxtMessage').val();
const date = $('#datetxt').val()
const code = $('#code').val();

const csvStr = data.map(m => [sms, date, code, m.producttype, m.mixer, m.quality].join(',')).join('\r\n');

console.log(csvStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="TxtMessage" value="TxtMessage"/>
<input type="hidden" id="datetxt" value="datetxt"/>
<input type="hidden" id="code" value="code"/>
```